# WinSCP - How to recognize if file was transferred successfully

Tags: scripting, sftp, winscp

I'm using WinSCP to automatically upload files through SFTP. I have turned on debug log on level 1. Is it possible to find out if the file was uploaded successfully? Thank you.

Part of log file:

```
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 File: "C:\files\file_20120830.gpg"
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Copying "C:\files\file_20120830.gpg" to remote directory started.
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Checking existence of file.
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 50, Number: 263
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Sent 54 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.539 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Received 33 bytes (0)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Read 4 bytes (29 pending)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Read 29 bytes (0 pending)
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 263
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Status code: 2
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 59, Number: 519
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Sent 63 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.555 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Received 33 bytes (0)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Read 4 bytes (29 pending)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Read 29 bytes (0 pending)
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 519
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Status code: 2
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Opening remote file.
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 75, Number: 771
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Sent 79 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.570 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Received 31 bytes (0)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Read 4 bytes (27 pending)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Read 27 bytes (0 pending)
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 27, Number: 771
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 0, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 1286
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 4096, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 1542
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 8192, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 1798
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 12288, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 2054
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 16384, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 2310
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 20480, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 2566
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Write request offset: 24576, len: 4096
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.586 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4135, Number: 2822
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.602 Sent 4139 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.602 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.602 Write request offset: 28672, len: 98261
> 2012-08-30 15:30:06.602 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 98300, Number: 3078
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Sent 98304 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Received 28 bytes (0)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1286
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 Status code: 0
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.617 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer, need to send at least another 440 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer, need to send at least another 440 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 There are 33208 bytes remaining in the send buffer, need to send at least another 440 bytes
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Detected network event
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Received 28 bytes (0)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1542
< 2012-08-30 15:30:06.633 Status code: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting WinSCP FAQ [How do I know that script completed successfully?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result):

> You can tell the result of script by WinSCP exit code. Code 0 indicates success, while 1 indicates an error. For more details refer to [scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) documentation.
>
> Batch script (specified using `/script` or `/command` [command-line switches](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting)) terminates with code 1 immediately once any error occurs. You can change this using [`option batch`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#batch) command.
>
> To find out why the script failed, inspect [session log](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging).
>
> For an example see:
>
> - [Guide to transfer automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#results);
> - [Retrying script/connection attempt](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_retry) example;
> - [Emailing script results](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_email) example.
>
> If you need a better control of error handling, consider using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) instead (e.g. from a [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell)).

Comment: The author always knows best:) Thank you, Martin, for advice and for your great tool!

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP has an option to log all your operations into an [XML log](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml).
you can then analyze the log to know exactly what happened during the session.

Answer (score 1):

Below,is the batch file I use to accomplish a sync from an ftp server to a local directory, deleting any changes on the local side.The batch file also saves a **XML log** of all transfers.

```
@echo off
cd %programfiles(x86)%\winscp\
start /b winscp.exe /log="C:\Sync\logs\!M-!D-!Y@!T.xml" /xmlgroups /command "open   ftp://username:password@ftp.foo.com" "synchronize local -delete -criteria=size     ""C:\Users\jdoe\Documents\Synced Docs"" /
```

The parameter that you will want to play with is the "**winscp.exe /log="C:\Sync\logs!M-!D-!Y@!T.xml" /xmlgroups**"